# android how to get view's drawingcache which view is heighter than screen

Tags: java, android, bitmap, scrollview, drawingcache

I have a ScrollView layout with "layout_width="match_parent",layout_height="match_parent"",and it have a child LinearLayout.the child is heighter than the screen.I want to get the child's bitmap,but use getDrawingCache() only get the picture which height equal the screen ,how can i get the child's complete picture.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

How about drawing the view on a canvas ?